# Improving on GROUP BY in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

#### Scenario

We have many people, these people go on trips with multiple stages/states (initially planning, then started, then returned_safely or ended in disaster).

I have a query which gets the right results, you can see it and play with it here:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2e096/1

However, I'm wondering if there's a better implementation, specifically one avoiding the use of `GROUP BY` and postgres' `bool_and`, potentially also avoiding a nested query.

#### What we want to know

> Who has never experienced a trip they didn't return safely from?

Or, put another way:

> Who has either: `1. Never planned or gone on a trip` OR `2. only ever returned safely`

**Clarifications**

- If there's a record for a person in the trips table, but no stages, they're planning a trip.

**Output**

Should be *at least* all the columns from the `person` table, if other columns come out too, that's fine.

#### Setup/Reproduction

```
CREATE TABLE people (person_name text, gender text, age integer);
INSERT INTO people (person_name, gender, age)
  VALUES ('pete', 'm', 10), ('alan', 'm', 22), ('jess', 'f', 24), ('agnes', 'f', 25), ('matt', 'm', 26);

CREATE TABLE trips (person_name text, trip_name text);
INSERT INTO trips (person_name, trip_name)
  VALUES ('pete', 'a'),
         ('pete', 'b'),
         ('alan', 'c'),
         ('alan', 'd'),
         ('jess', 'e'),
         ('matt', 'f');

CREATE TABLE trip_stages (trip_name text, stage text, most_recent boolean);
INSERT INTO trip_stages
  VALUES ('a', 'started', 'f'), ('a', 'disaster', 't'),
         ('b', 'started', 't'),
         ('c', 'started', 'f'), ('c', 'safe_return', 't'),
         ('e', 'started', 'f'), ('e', 'safe_return', 't');
```

#### Summary of the situation

- Pete has one trip which ended in disaster and one he just started
- Alan has one trip he returned from safely and one he is planning
- Jess has been on one trip, which she returned safely from
- Agnes has never even planned a trip
- Matt has planned a trip, but not started it yet

#### Solution

```
 person_name | gender | age
-------------+--------+-----
 jess        | f      | 24
 agnes       | f      | 25
```

- Jess (has been on one trip, which she returned safely from)
- Agnes (has never even planned a trip)

#### Working Query

```
SELECT people.* FROM people WHERE people.person_name IN (
  SELECT people.person_name FROM people
  LEFT OUTER JOIN trips
    ON trips.person_name = people.person_name
  LEFT OUTER JOIN trip_stages
    ON trip_stages.trip_name = trips.trip_name AND trip_stages.most_recent = 't'
  GROUP BY people.person_name
    HAVING bool_and(trips.trip_name IS NULL)
      OR bool_and(trip_stages.stage IS NOT NULL AND trip_stages.stage = 'safe_return')
)
```

#### Explanation

```
SELECT people.* FROM people WHERE people.person_name IN (
  -- All the people
  SELECT people.person_name FROM people

  -- + All their trips
  LEFT OUTER JOIN trips
    ON trips.person_name = people.person_name

  -- + All those trips' stages
  LEFT OUTER JOIN trip_stages
    ON trip_stages.trip_name = trips.trip_name AND trip_stages.most_recent = 't'

  -- Group by person
  GROUP BY people.person_name
    -- Filter to those rows where either:
    --   1. trip_name is always NULL (they've made no trips)
    --   2. Every trip has been ended with a safe return
    HAVING bool_and(trips.trip_name IS NULL)
      OR bool_and(trip_stages.stage IS NOT NULL AND trip_stages.stage = 'safe_return')
)
```

#### Question

Is there another way I could write this query? Without using `GROUP BY` and `bool_and` and ideally without using subqueries too? Perhaps some partition/window function?

**I'm using this to learn, so explanations/analysis of queries appreciated!**

I'm particularly interested in performance implications. e.g. What happens if people take thousands of trips? Do subqueries get out-performed by some other approach?

Comment: Why wouldn't Matt also be returned?  Based on your question it would seem that he has not been on a trip or been in a disaster and therefore would be part of the proper results.  Also why can't this just be 'select where stage <> disaster' (psuedo code obviously)

Comment: Matt has a trip (imagine he's planning it), he just hasn't started out on it yet. I realise in an ideal world, all trips would have stages, but that's part of the problem in this instance.

Comment: I posted an answer that bring also: `Matt` because it agree with you requirement: `Who has either: never gone on a trip OR only ever returned safely`

Comment: Added a clarification. If there's a trip record, they're *planning* a trip. I worded the question badly and used 'gone on', in my head that included planning, apologies!

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT p0.person_name FROM people p0
WHERE p0.person_name NOT IN (
 SELECT p.person_name FROM people p
 INNER JOIN trips t on p.person_name = t.person_name
 LEFT JOIN trip_stages s on t.trip_name = s.trip_name AND s.most_recent
 WHERE s.stage IS NULL OR s.stage != 'safe_return' );
```

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3416a/7/0)

Much easier to retrieve who *doesn't* fit and use a `NOT IN`.

EDIT: With the understanding that I am unable to be as concise in prose as I am in code, an expanded explanation per IMSoP's suggestion:

```
SELECT p0.person_name FROM people p0
-- The outer query exists to reverse the results of the inner query. The inner query
-- returns person names which have not arrived safely, the outer query returns the names,
-- via the NOT IN operator, which don't result from the inner query.
WHERE p0.person_name NOT IN (
 SELECT p.person_name FROM people p
-- Selecting from the same table via a different alias (p vs p0) is useful for avoiding
-- ambiguity.
 INNER JOIN trips t on p.person_name = t.person_name
-- The INNER JOIN returns results only where a value in people.person_name matches the
-- trips.person_name. This has the effect of removing any person_names from the inner
-- query who haven't taken any trips.
 LEFT JOIN trip_stages s on t.trip_name = s.trip_name AND s.most_recent
-- The LEFT JOIN links any rows created from the previous INNER JOIN to the trip_stages
-- table where trips. The terms of the LEFT JOIN restrict the matches the rows where the
-- most_recent column is true. Unlike the INNER JOIN, the LEFT JOIN does not eliminate
-- rows where there is no match. Where there is no match, the columns from the left side
-- of the join are still populated, those from the right side of the join are NULL.
 WHERE s.stage IS NULL OR s.stage != 'safe_return'
-- s.stage IS NULL indicates that, via the LEFT JOIN above, a trip was planned but not
-- begun. As we are specifying that the trip stage we are looking at is the last one
-- recorded, any value other than safe_return indicates that the row we are looking at
-- does not meet the conditions set by OP, and is thus to be included for elimination by
-- the outer query.
);
```

Comment: It would be good to expand on how this works and differs from the original, so that it can be applied more widely. Perhaps line-by-line breakdown comments like the OP used?

Comment: @IMSoP : Be careful what you ask for :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT distinct trips.person_name 
  FROM trips 
RIGHT JOIN trip_stages 
  ON trips.trip_name = trip_stages.trip_name 
WHERE trip_stages.most_recent = 't' 
  GROUP BY trips.person_name, trip_stages.stage 
  HAVING trip_stages.stage is not null 
  AND trip_stages.stage = 'safe_return'
```

Sorry for did multiple edits but got it working to get only the names of people here

Comment: This answer would be much improved if you explained a) how this query works, and b) how it differs from the one in the question. That way, other people coming upon this question later might be able to apply the principle to their queries, rather than it just being code supplied to the OP for free.

Answer (score 1):

You can use not `not exists` to select all people that do not have at least one trip that did not end in a safe return (which implies they either went on no trips or returned safely from all their trips) and do not have at least one planned trip that's not in a stage

```
select * from people p
where not exists (
    select 1 from trips t
    left join trip_stages ts on ts.trip_name = t.trip_name
    where ((ts.stage <> 'safe_return' -- did not end in safe return
      and ts.most_recent = 't') 
      or ts.trip_name is null) -- or does not have a trip stage
    and t.person_name = p.person_name
)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3416a/18

Comment: Hmm, not sure this gives the correct result? I've made an SQL fiddle here where you can test queries: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3416a/1

I think what's tripped you up here is that not having a disastrous trip doesn't mean you have got home safely.

Comment: @PeterHamilton second update to combine the multiple not exists into a single query.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, what you want is a list of all the persons for whom the number of trips they've been on (or that they're planning) is equal to the number of trips they've safely returned from. We can use a simple `GROUP BY .. HAVING` for this that compares both numbers:

```
   select p.person_name 
    from people p
    left join trips t on p.person_name = t.person_name
    left join trip_stages ts on t.trip_name = ts.trip_name
      and ts.most_recent = 't'
    group by p.person_name
    having count(t.trip_name) = 
        count(case when ts.stage = 'safe_return' then 1 else null end)
```

This

- computes the number of trips a person has made `count(t.trip_name)`
- computes the number of trips a person has safely returned from `count(case...)`
- compares both numbers and returns only the persons for whom they're equal

Comment: Interesting. Looks very similar to the approach I had but avoids the `bool_and`s. Any idea how it compares performance wise?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. PostgreSQL is not exactly my area of expertise (although SQL is).

Comment: Hmm, will have to run some tests on a big generated dataset and see how it compares...